# The app closes due to getting permissions without any error messages

Tags: android

My application is closed immediately after launching due permission request without an errors. This is my code, is here something wrong? Also, I post manifest file here to let you check it. I need bluetooth permission and data access.

The probem is in this line:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_MICROPHONE);
```

If I comment this, application will not close after launching.

```
private static final int REQUEST_MICROPHONE = 1;

private void askPermissions(){
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT};
    if (!hasPermissions(permissions)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_MICROPHONE);
    }
}
private boolean hasPermissions(String[] permissions) {
    if(permissions != null){
        for(String perm : permissions){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return false;
    }}
    return true;
}
```

And the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <!-- If you want to declare that your app is available to BLE-capable devices only, include the following in your app's manifest:/-->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.myapp.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your error stack trace

Comment: There are no errors or app crashes, the app just closed silently without any messages. In the end, I managed to find out the reason, it was in the wrong version of android and bluetooth permissions. Everything is fine now, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It was discrepancy between Android version and way to get permissions. Unfortunately, it was not any errors or other communications and I have to find a problem by luck.